# PHP multidimensional arrays: given the key retrieve value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this, made of arrays with pairs of ids and names:

```
$myarray
: array = 
  0: array = 
    53: string = Robert  
  1: array = 
    28: string = Carl  
  2: array = 
    32: string = Anna 
  3: array = 
    84: string = Mary  
  4: array = 
    59: string = Daniel
```

At certain point of my php script I'll get an id, and from this id I will need the name.

I  know that with an unidimensional array is a simple as $myarray[$id] but with the one above, how can I do it??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What would you `$id` look like?  In a multi-array, you just use more `[]`.  Like: `$myarray[0][53]` would be `"Robert"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know both IDs, it's easy:

```
$myarray[2][32] == 'Anna'
```

If you know first one, you can use following trick:

```
array_shift(array_values($myarray[2])) == 'Anna'
```

If you know only later, it might be wise to flatten your array first:

```
$newarray = array()
foreach($myarray as $element) {
  $newarray += $element;
}
echo $newarray[32]; // Anna
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider the structure.

If you'd like to retrieve 'Anna' if you have $id = 32:

```
$id = 32;
$name = null;
foreach ($myarray as $row) {
    if (isset($row[$id]) {
        $name = $row[$id];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your script assign the value of the two different IDs to `$id1` and `$id2` respectively, and then you can do this:

```
<?php 

$id1 = 0; //get your ID #1
$id2 = 53; //get your ID #2
echo $myarray[$id1][$id2]; //outputs Robert

?>
```

Hope this helps.